# What does 三房 mean?

Tags: word

According to recent news, 赌王三房的何超莲窦骁结婚，没想到把四房的何猷君和奚梦瑶夫妻俩弄上了热搜。奚梦瑶第一时间跑出来声明，自己没和窦骁谈过恋爱。吃瓜网友可能觉得没什么，但是奚梦瑶要是不即刻辟谣，这里面问题就很大了。奚梦瑶是四房的儿媳，窦骁是三房的女婿。

Is 房 an honorary title?

Answer (score 4):

In the old days, it was not uncommon for a rich Chinese man to have more than one wife.

The first and legal wife and her children are called 大房人 and collectively the 大房(The main house); The second wife and her children are called 二房(the second house), and so on.

> 赌王三房

三房(the third house) refers to the husband's third wife and her children

> 三房的何超莲 (the third house's 何超莲)

何超莲 is a child of the husband's third wife

Although Polygamy became illegal in modern times, many rich men still openly had more than one wife. Even if the other wives never got legally married to the man, society generally accepted they were also the wives of the family

Comment: My father was the elder son in the 3rd or 4th house of the family, he ranked 19th among all brothers in age. It was in the 20s of the last century

Answer (score 1):

赌王三房的何超莲窦骁结婚，没想到把四房的何猷君和奚梦瑶夫妻俩弄上了热搜。奚梦瑶第一时间跑出来声明，自己没和窦骁谈过恋爱。吃瓜网友可能觉得没什么，但是奚梦瑶要是不即刻辟谣，这里面问题就很大了。奚梦瑶是四房的儿媳，窦骁是三房的女婿。

Based on the description of the story, the man 赌王 (King of Gambling) has a family (last) name of 何. 何超莲 is the daughter born by his third wife 三房 (三房姨太太， the third wife). 何猷君 is the son born by his fourth wife 四房 (四房姨太太， the fourth wife).

**Is 房 an honorary title?**

No. It is just a title. When a rich man has multiple wives, he gives them each a specific room (房) to live in, which is named according to the order of the marriage with the woman. For example, if it is his third wife, the room is called 三房. The third wife is called 三房姨太太, which is abbreviated as 三房.

Comment: 房 here could be a room in the house, but it can also be a separate address, for example, my grandma ( 三 or 四房) and my father and uncles were not allowed even to visit the main house.

Comment: 姨太太 refers to the mistress, the head lady of 三房 is 三房太太

Comment: They lived under the same roof? I thought they (your grandma and father) had a separate house as the husband (your grandpa) is wealthy. Is concubine a good word to describe the relationship? @TangHo

Comment: @NanningYouth They lived in a separate house owned by my grandpa. The main house was where my grandpa and his first wife with their children lived. My grandma was one of my grandpa's four wives -- They were all wives. If by concubine you meant mistress then they wouldn't be qualified as 房, They'll be practically unrelated to the family

Comment: the term concubine (妾) refers to  a secondary wife, not a mistress